# Automaticly download library updates

Tags: java, libraries

I have a program that requires many libraries. I was wondering how I would make a program to automatically download library updates. Would I have to navigate each download page and their links to find a newer version from code? Or would I have to check these websites regularly and then put them on my own website for the program to download from?

Comment: You could maybe interface with git using their API, for any libraries that are stored there. But I'm not sure you'd want to allow updates automatically anyways, since some future update may change the library such that it borks your project. I'd say it might be better to stick with whatever is the latest upon project start, and update manually as needed or as determined to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a build tool like [`Maven`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or [`Gradle`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N10444).